# React-spring useTransition on carousel style component causing overlap during transition

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-spring

I'm trying to make a Modal which will display a few slides in a carousel-style component, and just make some simple enter/exit animations on slide change. I'm using the [useTransition hook](https://react-spring.io/hooks/use-transition) from react-spring, and the problem is that when a transition occurs, there are a few moments where the outgoing slide (which is fading out) and incoming slide (which is fading in) are both in the modal. This causes rendering issues where the height is doubled because the same width needs to be shared by the two slides.

[Here is a code sandbox demonstrating the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/overlapping-transition-react-spring-egj7m?file=/src/App.js)

I've tried following some guides online but unfortunately they seem to work with an older version of react-spring where the return value of the hook differed.

I have also tried changing the styling of the containing div to `position: absolute` so that it will allow overlapping components, but then the modal does not have the correct height and width dimensions to properly display the content. To try to get around this, I've tried

1. Storing the dimensions as state
2. Initializing with large values
3. Applying these dims to a div that contains the slide
4. Keeping ref to the div, and grabbing the real computed dims in a `useEffect` hook, then updating the state dims

This sort of gives the effect that I want, but has two major problems - computed height doesn't seem to update properly and this doesn't respond to change in viewport. It feels like bad responsive design, despite kinda doing what I want. Here's a [sandbox with this workaround](https://codesandbox.io/s/overlapping-transition-react-spring-workaround-8wrh7?file=/src/App.js).

I'm not very strong with css and I feel like there is something elegant that can solve this, would be much appreciated if y'all have any thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue. with a simple enter/exit transition.

solved it with the [*exitBeforeEnter: true* property](https://react-spring.io/hooks/use-transition#properties):
*Ensures any items leaving animate out before the new items animate in*
I noticed that it is a relatively [new addition to the library](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/pull/1773) (since version 9.4.0).  
fixed your sandbox [in this fork](https://codesandbox.io/embed/overlapping-transition-react-spring-forked-vmbcls?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: Nice discovery, used it too! This also allows us to prevent setting `position: absolute` as I saw in several examples, which was an old trick specifically to avoid the content layout shift as experimented on here while fading from one to the other component. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One solution that worked for me was using:

position: absolute

This works since each element inside the animated div won't depend on the animation.

Comment: It says in the question that he tried `position: absolute` and it did not work as expected.